# compare the current and previous version of the same array for change in value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a following data array :

```
[{"name":"joseph","time":"0","status":"Idle"}] //there are multiple objects inside the array
```

This array of objects is generated every second by a node js service. I want to compare the newly created array with the previously created array to check for the change of the status.

eg

case 1

```
newly created 
[{"name":"joseph","time":"0","status":"Idle"}]

previously created
[{"name":"joseph","time":"0","status":"Idle"}]
```

comparing the status of new and previous object : No change in status

case 2

```
newly created 
[{"name":"joseph","time":"0","status":"Calling"}]

previously created

[{"name":"joseph","time":"0","status":"Idle"}]
```

comparing the status of new and previous object : status has changed

I hope you get the point.
If the status has changed then assign the current time to the time key;
I'm not able to figure out how to save the previous array and compare it with the newly created array.

What I have done so far:

```
newarray = [{"name":"joseph","time":"0","status":"Calling"}];
previousarray = newarray;
for(i=0;i<=newarray.length;i++){
  for(j=0;j<previousarray.length;j++){
if(previousarray[j].status != newarray[i].status){

  newarray[i].time = moment().format('H:mm:ss');
}
  }
}
```

but this doesn't work. I get error like :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

How do I do it?

Comment: what means changes? in order, in properties?

Comment: change in properties. for eg here the status property of the objects

Comment: but the changes are stil at the same index?

Comment: I think this is just a case of index being out of bounds causing undefined object.
newarray[1] is undefined

Comment: In your loop use < instead of <=.. answer properly covered below by @gyc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can do in the below possible way. assuming `newly_created` & `previously_created`

```js
newly_created  = [{"name":"joseph","time":"0","status":"Calling"}, {"name":"joseph - 2","time":"0","status":"Idle"}, {"name":"joseph - 3","time":"0","status":"Calling"}];

previously_created = [{"name":"joseph","time":"0","status":"Idle"}, {"name":"joseph - 2","time":"0","status":"Calling"},  {"name":"joseph - 3","time":"0","status":"Calling"}];


newly_created.forEach(function(newArrObj, index){
 
 if(newArrObj.status !== previously_created[index].status){
  // newArrObj.time = moment().format('H:mm:ss');
              newArrObj.time = new Date().toTimeString().split(' ')[0];
 }
});

console.log('New Array  : ', newly_created);
```

Comment: this helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

First your `previousArray` is a reference to the `newArray` using `=`

Use the spread operator syntax instead:

`const previousArray = [...newArray];`

Then in the first loop you have `<=` instead of `<`

```js
const newarray = [{"name":"joseph","time":"0","status":"Calling"}];
const previousarray = [...newarray];

for(let i = 0; i < newarray.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < previousarray.length; j++) {
    if(previousarray[j].status != newarray[i].status) {
       newarray[i].time = moment().format('H:mm:ss');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Additionally, it's good practice to not modify an array directly but to create and return a new array. (immutability) You can do that using Array.map() in this case. See https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
newarray = {"name":"joseph","time":"0","status":"Calling"};
previousarray = newarray;
if(previousarray['status'] !== newarray['status']){

  newarray['time'] = "date-time";

}
```